# char to wchar_t results in heap corruption

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I have the following code

```
char *GetBytesString(char message[])
{
    wchar_t utf16_str;
    char *ptr;
    mbstowcs(&utf16_str, message, sizeof(message));
    ptr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(utf16_str) + 2);
    memcpy(ptr, &utf16_str, sizeof(utf16_str));
    return ptr;
}
```

Whenever I try to call it, I get an error saying that Heap corruption has occurred around utf16_str. What can I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: It should have been wchar_t *utf16_str

Answer (score 4):

Stop overwriting random memory.

This:

```
wchar_t utf16_str;
```

Only reserves space for *one*  wide character, and then you write the entire converted string on top of that.

You should do the `malloc()` first, but you need to use `strlen()` to figure out how many characters are going to be needed. Then convert into the allocated buffer, and return that.

There are more issues, for instance `sizeof message` doesn't work like you probably expect it to.

Also, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 1):

It should have been `wchar_t *utf16_str` instead of `wchar_t utf16_str`. Refer the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy.aspx) for the examples from msdn for `mbstowcs`  .